# Using revision dates in footer in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a manual that is numbered and put together as one section however the footer has the date the page was revised.  Is there anyway I can revise just one page in the footer without having to make every page a separate section?

Answer (score 0):

Under Header & Footer Tools (select the Footer), Design, Options check Different First Page.